# GET request returning 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, get

I have a spring boot application where I am just sending a GET request to fetch some data from a pre populated list.
The list exists inside the controller class. When I am hitting the URL, I am constantly getting 404 error.

**Student.java**

```
package com.SpringBootDemo.entities;

public class Student {

    private Integer studentId;
    private String studentName;

    public Student(Integer studentId, String studentName) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }


}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.SpringBootDemo.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.SpringBootDemo.entities.Student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/students")
public class StudentController {

    private static final List<Student> STUDENTS = Arrays.asList(
            new Student(1,"ABC"),
            new Student(2,"DEF"),
            new Student(3,"HIJ"));

    @GetMapping(path = "{studentId}")
    public Student getStudentById(@PathVariable("studentId")Integer studentId) 
    {
        System.out.println("inside the controller");
        return STUDENTS.stream()
                .filter(student -> studentId.equals(student.getStudentId()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalStateException("Student with id "+studentId+" doesn't exist"));

    }

}
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_project
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Pblock@20
server.port = 8081
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My stacktrace

```
020-06-01 15:07:29.879  INFO 21012 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-01 15:07:30.275  INFO 21012 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2020-06-01 15:07:30.281  INFO 21012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-01 15:07:30.281  INFO 21012 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
```

Comment: so what url are you sending the GET request to ?

Comment: 404 only means either your application is not deployed properly or you are hitting the wrong URL. please double check your URL is correct (context path + url)

Comment: Your endpoint should look like `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/students/1`, assuming service is running in `local` and port `8080`

Comment: My server port is 8081 and I am hitting `http://localhost:8081/api/v1/students/1`

Comment: I created an end point as yours and I was able to access the path via your provided URL in comments! check your configurations not URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is wrong. change @GetMapping(path = "{studentId}") to @GetMapping("/{studentId}")

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/students")
public class StudentController {

    private static final List<Student> STUDENTS = Arrays.asList(
            new Student(1,"ABC"),
            new Student(2,"DEF"),
            new Student(3,"HIJ"));

    @GetMapping("/{studentId}")
    public Student getStudentById(@PathVariable("studentId")Integer studentId) 
    {
        System.out.println("inside the controller");
        return STUDENTS.stream()
                .filter(student -> studentId.equals(student.getStudentId()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalStateException("Student with id "+studentId+" doesn't exist"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but that didn't work, however, when I added @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=StudentController.class) to my base class, it worked.

Comment: Just FYI , appending "/" is not required [ optional ] ,it is automatically handled in this case. Have you seen that hitting localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/ has the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

When I added @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=StudentController.class) to my base class, it worked.

**SpringSecurityDemoApplication**

```
package com.SpringSecurityDemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.SpringBootDemo.controller.StudentController;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=StudentController.class)
public class SpringSecurityDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As You have not given the proper url, the url you are hitting is not recognizing for get. Hence throwing 404 not found status.
Change the mapping of your rest controller as @GetMapping("/{studentId}") and then hit the url http://localhost:8081/api/v1/students/1

Comment: this answer is provided before and did not fix the problem as is said.